# How to convert word selection to html?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, vsto

How does the selected text in Word to convert to HTML format with minimal losses, by VSTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try this, `Inspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("FileSaveAsHtml")` if you'd like to save text into html format.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa434602%28v=office.12%29.aspx)